# Mongodb - Difference between running "mongo" and "mongod" databases

Tags: mongodb, shell, database

So, I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, but when I run mongo as a daemon (using mongod --fork or just mongod), I see different database content than if I just run "mongo" on the host machine.

My only assumption is that the data is being stored somewhere other than /data/db when it's running just the shell, and switches to /data/db when I boot the mongod. In that case, how do I get at my data when running mongod?

Comment: not sure what you are asking here, but mongod is the database server and mongo is the client. so what do you mean by "I see different database content"?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

I think there is some confusion here.

`mongod` is the "Mongo Daemon" it's basically the host process for the database. When you start `mongod` you're basically saying *"start the MongoDB process and run it in the background"*. `mongod` has several default parameters, such as storing data in `/data/db` and running on port 27017.

`mongo` is the command-line shell that connects to a specific instance of `mongod`. When you run `mongo` with no parameters it defaults to connecting to the localhost on port 27017. If you run `mongo` against an invalid machine:port combination then it will fail to connect (and tell you as much).

Ideally, when doing anything other than just "playing around", you'll use the [Command Line Parameters](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Command+Line+Parameters) for starting `mongod`. By the same measure you should start the `mongo` shell with explicit instructions.

Based on your description, I think you may be encountering an issue regarding the use of default databases. Try starting `mongo` with the following (where `dbname` is your database name)

```
./mongo localhost:27017/dbname
```

Comment: To confirm, if I want to have a quick look/make an off hand edit, I use mongo...however when in production, I run mongod after which the API or scripts can interact with it?

Answer (score 24):

Yes, this might be a naive answer to this question but I am putting it forward so people can understand it easily!

**Mongod:**

> mongod

(Short for Mongo Daemon) is a background process used by MongoDB server to get things done. This process is responsible for managing the whole MongoDB server tasks such as accepting requests, responding to users, managing memory requirement of MongoDB server operations and other things essential for MongoDB Server to run.

**TLDR;** Basically it is the MongoDB server

**Mongo:**

> Mongo

on the other hand, is an interactive JavaScript shell interface to MongoDB, which provides a powerful interface for system administrators as well as a way for developers to test queries and operations directly with the database. mongo also provides a fully functional JavaScript environment for use with a MongoDB

**TLDR;** Basically I think it as mongodb client which can be used as a shell to get access to MongoDB database server run my mongod instances

Answer (score 4):

Mongo`D`(Daemon process).
In simple "Hello world" words - You **won't** communicate Mongod directly.
Instead, you use **DB client**:

- [Mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) (run `mongo`) - In an interactive JavaScript interface (-or- run `mongosh` [the new MongoDB Shell](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-the-new-shell)).
- [Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) - Graphical view of MongoDB (Or [studio 3t](https://studio3t.com/) and other GUI apps).
- **Drivers** (Like [node](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) -or- [JAVA](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) drivers).

And you find more tools like this.

In your case, you want to use **Mongo Shell** client (`mongo` command).

### Visual

A great way to see "the client" - "in action" is to open two terminals (or more) side by side.

Run `mongod` (mongo command will not work without MongoDB server install and running), then run `mongo`:

[image]

**Output (`1 connection: application mongo shell`}**
[image]

Next, run some [CRUD](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/) Operations and see the messages under `mongod`.

Same idea if you connect **Compass client**:
[image]

Manage mongodb processes docs (Change data directory, Port and so on):
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/

Comment: I did the following steps and when I try and run `mongod` I get error:  `bash: mongod: command not found` OR `'mongod' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.   1)  Install MongoDB `5.0.6` using `.msi` installer and select *not* to run as a Windows Service,  2) Create directory at `/data/db`   3)  Install MongoDB Shell `1.3.1`.  [The docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#run-mongodb-community-edition-from-the-command-interpreter) don't describe how to use `mongod`.

Comment: Update, answer to my question is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41507803  essentially `You need to add Mongo's bin folder to the "Path" Environment Variable`.  I'm not sure why this doesn't happen by default when installing MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

**Mongod (Mongo Daemon)**

- Basically host process for the database.
- i.e. when you start mongod that basically saying that ***"start the MongoDB process and run it in the background."***
- In simple terms **"Mongod basically starts the server"**
- Also known as **server** for the MongoDB.

**Mongo**

- It's the **shell**, **client**, **JS interface** that used to **interact with MongoDB Server(Mongod)**
- In simple terms **"Client which connect to the Mongod"**