# mongo command not recognized when trying to connect to a mongodb server

Tags: mongodb

I am following the tutorials at docs.mongodb.org, I have completed the first tutorial which was to install mongodb on a Windows machine. I am now at the second stage which is getting started with mongodb development.

I am stuck at the first stage of this section which instructs me to type `mongo` into a system prompt. When I do this I simply get an error message saying the following:

```
'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

I know this is probably something quite simple that I am doing wrong, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you really complete the tutorial? I'd guess you skipped a step or two. :)  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/  Download, Setup, Start are the three headings -- you'll need to perform each of the steps listed. Then, from the same folder as you installed into, type `mongo`.

Comment: Yes I did complete the whole tutorial, had the test database they suggest in that tutorial working and everything. In fact I did the fourth heading that you appear to have missed out, friend.

Comment: I missed out on a step? I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: MongoDB as a Windows Service

Comment: On my development boxes, I never run mongodb as a service. That's an optional step. So, I didn't miss anything that's required.

Comment: I didn't say you missed anything that's required, just felt you were trying to imply that I hadn't completed the tutorial when I'd actually done the whole thing without missing anything out.

Comment: @Kristian82 i have this problem too. when i run mongo :
c:\Program Files\MongoDB>mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.2
connecting to: test
2015-04-18T11:26:12.602-0700 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
2015-04-18T11:26:12.609-0700 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.
0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179

Comment: From monog db version 6, you can use mongosh, download and install it, then first run mongod in a terminal and finally run mongosh in a new terminal.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/install/

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You need to run `mongod` first in one cmd window then open another and type `mongo`. Make sure you updated your Windows Path environment variable too so that you don't have to navigate to the directory you have all of the mongo binaries in to start the application. To update the Path variable:

Go to Control Panel > System & Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > navigate to the Path variable hit Edit and add `;C:\mongodb` to the Path (or whatever the directory name is where MongoDB is located (the semi-colon delimits each directory).

Comment: Sorry friend, this has not resolved my problem. I will take WiredPrarie's advice and refer back to the original tutorial, although this is not explicitly stated in the second tutorial only to type mongo in a system prompt.

Comment: What did you add to the Windows path variable? If you're in the directory that the binaries are stored you should be able to run mongod.

Comment: And just to be clear you need to type mongod in one cmd window first to get the mongod server instance running (keep this window open), then open a new cmd window and type mongo.

Comment: I added the directory you said to the path variable. I'll just have to navigate to that directory, every time I want to use it, it's ok.

Comment: Ok but it needs to be the exact directory that the binaries are stored in e.g c:\mongodb\bin

Comment: I know, I worked that much out - just got bored of trying. I'm sure it'll be something stupid I'm doing.

Comment: hmmm...like you said uninstall mongodb and go through the tutorial again

Comment: Need to add path till `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin` then it will work.(for windows machine)

Comment: Thanks @br3w5 and Tejashree it should to be full path to the bin folder of the mongo server

Answer (score 288):

### You need to add Mongo's `bin` folder to the "Path" Environment Variable

Here's how on Windows 10:

1. Find Mongo's **bin** folder.

If you're not sure where it is, it's probably in `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\` *3.4 was the latest stable version at the time, this will be different for you probably.*

It should look like this:

[image: This is what Mongo's bin folder looked like for version 3.4, the important thing is it's whatever folder contains mongod.exe.]
*Notice this is the path to mongo.exe and mongod.exe. Adding this folder to the Path variable is telling Windows to search in this folder for executables matching your command when you run something in cmd. The search starts with the current working dir, and if it doesn't find your exe, goes on to search all the paths in Path till it finds it or it doesn't and it gives you that error you saw.*

2. Copy the path to the bin folder. It should be `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\` (*Or whatever version you're using*)
3. Press <kbd>win</kbd>, type `env`, Windows will suggest "Edit the System Environment Variables", click that.

[image: How to find the system environment variables.]

4. On the Advanced tab, click "Environment Variables"

[image: The Advanced tab in System Properties contains the Environment Variables.]

5. Highlight the "Path" variable, click "Edit":

[image: You want to edit the Path variable to add Mongo's bin folder to it.]

6. This will bring up the "Edit environment variable" window, click "New"

[image: Add a new folder to the Path variable]

7. This will start a new line in the list of folders:

[image: A new line in the Path variable.]

8. Paste your path to the bin folder. Make sure it ends with a `\` like so:

[image: Paste the location of the bin folder.]

9. Press "OK", "OK", "OK"
10. Restart anything where you want to use the new path: CMD windows, Visual Studio terminals, etc. *(Thanks to @id.ot for their comment)*

Now you should be able to run `mongod` and `mongo` from anywhere in a command window.

Comment: This is how you reply to a question. Hats of to you sir. Thank you very much.

Comment: I guess 6th step is not required, which requires variable name ? , only editing the path variable is required as mentioned in step 5 , check [this](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/08/install-setup-and-start-mongodb.html).

Comment: @stom You're clicking "New" on the "Environment Variables" Window - that's not what my instructions say. If you click "Edit" instead, you are presented with an "Edit environment variable" window. Then, you click new, and you are adding a new folder location to the Path Environment Variable. However, I can see where one would be confused by this. I will update my answer to show the Edit environment variable window. Thanks.

Comment: Also had to restart Visual Studio Code (my current IDE).

Comment: Also, if you were using Visual Studio code like me, you may have to restart the IDE in order for the updated path to be usable.

Comment: I had to reboot the system in order for it to take effect. (possibly could have restarted some service without shutting the computer down) but it works perfect. A fine upvote from me.

Comment: Thankyou so much it was great explanation and thanks @id.ot we need to restart to get the updated path :)

Comment: Don't forget to restart your computer after adding the path variable! Mine didn't work until I did a restart.

Answer (score 28):

It is probably too late, but for the sake of others (like me) who faced the same problem. It is all about the little '\' at the end of the path variable.
When you insert the path to MongoDB's bin directory at the end of the PATH windows variable, do not forget to put the '\' (Backslash) at the end, which tells windows it is a directory and not an executable named bin... 
e.g. I:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin**\**

Comment: I will also mention, make sure you don't have any white space after the semicolon. Otherwise the path will not be recognized. Avoid this: `...; C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin`, it should be `...;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin`

Comment: This was the exact problem for me. Thank you for your comment @dilion.dani

Answer (score 7):

Seems like, The environmental variable is not correctly set up.

Go to the mongodb installation folder and get the executable files (mongo.exe, mongod.exe etc) location. (In my case) Something like :

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin
```

Then go to :

```
Panel > System & Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables
```

Find the `PATH` variable and edit its value. Then add `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin` and don't forget to separate each values with `;`. Now confirm and exit.

Comment: after  enter to this folder C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin use CMD   MongoD work For me

Comment: There are 2 paths Users Variable and System Variables. Should they both be added ?

Comment: @Shulz Not sure, but both should work. Try user path first.

Answer (score 5):

You need to be in the right directory,
i.e.

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\bin
```

and the path you are installing into needs to be the correct one

i.e.

```
mongod --dbpath 
C:\Users\Name\Documents\myWebsites\nodetest1
```

A folder named "data" must also exist in your project folder.

Comment: Good call. You also need to be in the mongodb directory when running the command.

Answer (score 5):

if still not working for you then just close all of your command prompts and then again open and run mongo, mongoimport, mongodb from anywhere it ll work because after setting the path variable command prompt should be restarted.

Answer (score 4):

For add environment variable please add **\** after bin like below

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\
```

Then try below code in command prompt to run mongo server from parent folder of data folder.

```
mongod -dbpath ./data
```

For my case I am unable to run mongo from command prompt(normal mode). You should **run as administrator**.
It also works on git bash.

Comment: mongo.exe works but not mongod on admin priviledge

Comment: Just realized on Mongo version 5 it's named as 'mongos' not 'mongod'

Answer (score 3):

I download MongoDB Community 6.0.0 and same issue occure.

> mongo command not recognized

That's my bin folder by default and there is no `mongo.exe` present.

[image: That's my bin folder, and there is no mongo.exe present]

so [Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0) answer where you have to download it manually.

If still have confusion then first go to [this link](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell?jmp=docs) and download the file. After Extraction you see this.

[image]

Go inside ***bin folder***. You will file 2 Files like

[image]

Copy them and add them in the following path.

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin
```

Don't forget to add this path into Environment Variable `Path` and you are good to go...

Instead of typing mongo in terminal, type -> *`mongosh`* or to check version -> *`mongosh --version`*

Comment: This is the best answer in my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
.\mongod  --dbpath c:\......
```

Comment: I don't know why I got edited.
The solution that worked for me was .\mongod --dbpath c:\...

Comment: --db path followed by C:\Program Files\MongoDb...or default directory of Mongo? (C:\data\db)

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have the environment variable set up. 
 1. Right click on my computer
 2. properties
 3. advanced system settings
 4. environment variables
 5. edit the PATH variable. and add ;"C:\mongoDb\bin\" to the PATH variable.

Path in the quotes may  differ depending on your installation directory. Do not forget the last '\' as it was the main problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `MongoDb` bin path in Environment path with `\` worked for me

This is what my system path

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
...
...
Other path variables
...
;C:\Users\hitesh.sahu\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\
```

Make sure:-

- Environment path must not have space between them
- Environment path must be saparated by `;`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from having a `Path` variable, the directory `C:\data\db` is mandatory.

Create this and the error shall be solved.

Answer (score 1):

before using MongoDB you have to run it locally to do that:

- go to `bin` folder you will find at `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin`
- open `mongod.exe`. will open a new terminal with server details.
- open `mongo.exe`. will open the shell which allows you to interact with the database.

Answer (score 0):

putting forward slash "/" at the end of path to bin of mongodb solved my problem.

Comment: Isn't this forward slash?

Comment: that's a forward slash.

Comment: putting backward slash "\" at the end of path ..... \bin\ will solved the problem.. you can run mongod or mongo from anywhere in command prompt

Answer (score 0):

1.To begin using MongoDB,
Open CMD with admin privilege and type :
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongo.exe"

2.To create data directory(open another cmd terminal)
cd C:
md "\data\db"
3. To start your mongo DB database, type in cmd the following lines:
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath="c:\data\db"
(The --dbpath option points to your database directory.)
[you can also do step 2 and 3 first and then step 1]

ref:https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

mostly, this is not working because you haven't set the path, in my case too I haven't set a path. so this can be solved by following the steps.:

1. Go to the control panel
2. Click on  system and security
3. then click on the system
4. click on the advanced system setting
5. click on environment variable
6. click on the path in user variables
7. Edit the path
8. Add a new path
9. (copy the path from local discs c /program files/mongodb/bin), it should look similar to this C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin
10. paste it there and click ok
11. close the vs code and reopen it

Answer (score 0):

Just use `mongotop` instead of `mongod` in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the **6.0.1** version then in place of **`mongo`** use **`mongod`** for example in place of mongo --version use **`mongod --v`** OR **`mongod --version`** and it will work.

**NOTE"** **`Make sure environment variable is set properly. The main reason I found is, earlier in BIN folder there was an exe with name mongo.exe but in latest version it is no longer available`**

Answer (score 0):

The difference in versions creates a problem.
To solve the error that is being displayed, follow these steps:

1. Inside the "C" folder create "data" folder and inside data create a "db" folder. Both folder names should be in lowercase letters.
2. Set the path in the environment variables. Copy the path "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin". Then, go to "This PC" -> Properties -> Settings -> Search -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables -> User Variables -> Path -> Edit -> New -> Paste the copied path from step 2, which is "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin" -> OK.
3. In the same "Environment Variables" page, scroll down to the "System Variables" section, select "Path" -> Edit -> New -> OK.
4. Close all the windows or pages related to environment variables.
5. In the MongoDB Community Download Server website page , go to the "Product" -> "Tools" -> download the shell.
6. After unzipping the downloaded file, cut the "mongosh.exe" file and paste it into the path "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin".
7. In the same folder, press Shift and right-click, then select "Open PowerShell window here". When you type "mongo" and press enter in the PowerShell window, the same error will appear. This happens because in version 5, it was "mongo", but in version 6, it has changed to "mongosh". So, when you enter "mongosh", the error will not occur.

By following these steps, hopefully, you won't encounter any further errors.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\ path you will find a folder named bin .. right click on it and open it in the terminal ... hope it helps! (for Windows)

[This is the path you have to go on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z20oD.png)

Answer (score 0):

doesn't work in version 6.0 or above, you can modify using mongosh (either by installing it at the time of installing mongodb) or Open mongoDB Compass asnd find the shell there in bottom left corner.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAMEm.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The `mongo` command line tool is no longer shipped with MongoDB version 6.0. This tool is deprecated and replaced by the new `mongosh` shell. This tool may have been installed depending on how you installed the MongoDB package.