# .mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: mongodb, reactjs

I have installed mongo db. Then when i tried to execute .mongo or mongo in command prompt. It's showing this error:

> .mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

I'm following some tutorial, So I'm not able to move further because i got stuck here.

Comment: the command ought to be "mongod" and not "mongo", if this is not working we need more information on which program you've installed and/or which tutorial you are following.

Comment: I was following one tutorial. In that they told mongo not mongod. Anyways i tried both

Comment: Helpful answer that worked for me is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41507803

Comment: Open command prompt with admin mode and execute mongo

Answer (score 58):

For those that want a step-by-step guide:

### You need to add Mongo's `bin` folder to the "Path" Environment Variable

Here's how on Windows 10:

1. Find Mongo's **bin** folder.

If you're not sure where it is, it's probably in `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\` *3.4 was the latest stable version at the time, this will be different for you probably.*

It should look like this:

[image: This is what Mongo's bin folder looked like for version 3.4, the important thing is it's whatever folder contains mongod.exe.]
*Notice this is the path to mongo.exe and mongod.exe. Adding this folder to the Path variable is telling Windows to search in this folder for executables matching your command when you run something in cmd. The search starts with the current working dir, and if it doesn't find your exe, goes on to search all the paths in Path till it finds it or it doesn't and it gives you that error you saw.*

2. Copy the path to the bin folder. It should be `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\` (*Or whatever version you're using*)
3. Press <kbd>win</kbd>, type `env`, Windows will suggest "Edit the System Environment Variables", click that.

[image: How to find the system environment variables.]

4. On the Advanced tab, click "Environment Variables"

[image: The Advanced tab in System Properties contains the Environment Variables.]

5. Highlight the "Path" variable, click "Edit":

[image: You want to edit the Path variable to add Mongo's bin folder to it.]

6. This will bring up the "Edit environment variable" window, click "New"

[image: Add a new folder to the Path variable]

7. This will start a new line in the list of folders:

[image: A new line in the Path variable.]

8. Paste your path to the bin folder. Make sure it ends with a `\` like so:

[image: Paste the location of the bin folder.]

9. Press "OK", "OK", "OK"
10. Open a new cmd window to work with the updated path variable.

Now you should be able to run `mongod` and `mongo` from anywhere in a command window.

Comment: This if from far the best guide I've seen for this task. Thank you!

Comment: getting this error

{"t":{"$date":"2023-04-05T20:19:48.110+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}

Comment: @RohanDevaki the error was very likely due to an invalid default path of `mongod`, which is specified to `C:/data/db`. You can either create the required folders on ur own or just use `--dbpath PATH_HERE` to change the default path when initiating.

Answer (score 30):

I think you might have forgotten setting Environment variables for Mongo’s
bin folder.Follow this, and try again: [Set Environment variables for mongo db's bin folder path](https://dangphongvanthanh.wordpress.com/2017/06/12/add-mongos-bin-folder-to-the-path-environment-variable/)

Answer (score 21):

If you have installed the 6.0.1 version then in place of mongo use mongod for example in place of mongo --version use mongod --v and it will work fine.

I have set the path and everything maybe the error is only in this version.

Answer (score 14):

1. Install the 6.0.1 version (or simply use latest version).

[image: mongodb website]

2. Set the path of "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin" in system environment variables by editing "path".

[image: environment variable entry]

[image: environment variable mongodb entry]

3. Open "cmd" and type "mongod --version" in place of "mongo --version".

[image: mongodb check]

Comment: {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-05T20:19:48.110+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}

getting this error

Answer (score 9):

If there is no mongo.exe in your bin file, then download the mongo shell - mongosh from [here](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell)

Use mongosh instead of mongo in the command line.

Check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0/73208435#73208435) from dododo : "mongo shell no longer ships with server binaries."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 6):

try below command if you face like -
'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

```
C:\Users\Vishal Bramhankar>mongo
'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Vishal Bramhankar>mongo --version
'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Vishal Bramhankar>mongod --version
db version v6.0.3
Build Info: {
    "version": "6.0.3",
    "gitVersion": "f803681c3ae19817d31958965850193de067c516",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "windows",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}

C:\Users\Vishal Bramhankar>
```

Answer (score 5):

Open "cmd" and type `mongod --version` in place of `mongo --version`.

It is because you have installed a newer version of Mongo (6.0+).

[image]

Comment: your answer is also correct, kindly provide more commands or commands list for mongo in cmd.

Answer (score 4):

Try writing `mongosh` in command line

and you may have to install mongosh because ↓

> The mongo command line tool is no longer shipped with MongoDB version
> 6.0. This tool is deprecated and replaced by the new mongosh shell. This tool may have been installed depending on how you installed the
> MongoDB package. If it was not you can always download it
>
> **-Doug_Duncan on the mongodb's community forums**

mongosh download link: https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell

Answer (score 3):

1. Find the path to the MongoDB installed from driver name to .bin.

   C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin
2. Add to the user's path variable.
   [image]

Comment: still not working when i add the path to the env maybe it was mongodb 6 problem

Comment: Yep, version 6.0 sucks

Answer (score 3):

If you are using version 6.0 and your facing problem like

```
"mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"
```

Then just use `mongod --help` or else for version `mongod --version`.

And people using Windows, try version 5.0.13, since the latest version is not working for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

`mongo` is deprecated in the new version
better to use `mongosh` once installed

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you downloaded MongoDB version 6 and installed it already. Then do the followings:

- Download MongoDB shell from [enter link description here](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell2)
- Extract it and paste it as a separate folder inside C Drive
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk7eg.png)
- Considering that you have already pasted your path inside the environment variables now paste the mongo shell that path also inside the path.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSbe2.png)
- create a data folder inside C Drive  if you want to (optional)
- open a new cmd and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Spending 30 minutes on this error Finally, I run this command only because the environment variable was not only an issue. For me version 6.0 not working I have set the environment variable many times but failed. finally, I downgrade the version and use 5.9, and set its environment variable too, and run this command  its working fine now.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxrLi.png)

Download the MongoDB Shell

Answer (score 1):

Installing an old version might work, and if you are on version 6,
use
 `mongod --version`
instead of `mongo`

Answer (score 1):

It is because in mongodb version 6.0 we are downloading shell or mongosh separately so we have to add mongosh to our mongodb binary or bin folder.
Check the link so you can see images.

First Download MongoDB community server
[Download MongoDB community server](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community)

When installing mongo community server
[Copy Data Directory or Path marked by red arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPVjO.png)
then complete installation.

Download monogsh shell zip file and extract zip
[MongoDB Shell Download](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell)

After that cut mongosh file from extracted files,
[Cut this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWrHB.png)

Goto earlier copied path(Data Directory Path)

[paste mongosh inside this path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgjiE.png)
paste  mongosh file

[Add the Data Directory or path to Environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smDeh.png)

finish now you can check by mongosh --version
if you want it mongo then rename mongosh inside data directory path to mongo and mongo --version

Answer (score 1):

> **The "mongo" shell has been superseded by "mongosh"**

Use this command `mongosh --version` to check mongo shell version

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed >=6.0 version and even though after configuring environmental variables you are facing this error try this

1. **In cmd enter mongod command instead of mongo**

After entering the command if you encounter following issue 'DataDirectory data/db not found' then In C drive create data folder and inside data folder create db folder

Now try executing mongod command again

Optional: install mongosh through following url for executing mongocommands
https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell

Comment: this is quite foggy and almost unrelated to original question

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB latest version 6.0.2 there is no mongo.exe executable in bin folder. To execute commands you have to install mongosh shell.  - [Install from here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/install/)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error 'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I am connecting the Atlas cluster with the mongo shell with version 4.4.
'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
I used mongoshell version instead of the 4.4 version and it worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on version 6, use  mongod --version instead of mongo

it worked for me. please wait for some minutes if you are installed and did every configuration right wait some minutes if your laptop is running slow.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem faced

I encountered a problem while trying to start the MongoDB server after downloading the latest version. Initially, I received an error message, and after adding the MongoDB bin folder path to the environmental variables, the server started successfully. However, I then faced an issue starting the MongoDB shell.

### Steps to install used before the problem

Before experiencing the problem, I followed these installation steps:

1. Download the latest version of MongoDB from the official website. You can find the downloads page [here](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community).
2. Install MongoDB by running the downloaded installer.

### My mistake

The mistake I made was assuming that the MongoDB shell, known as "mongosh," would be included in the main MSI installer or binary files. However, it is now a separate download and needs to be installed independently.

### My solution

To resolve the issue and successfully start the MongoDB shell, follow these steps:

1. Download the MongoDB shell separately. You can find the official downloads page [here](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell).
2. Once the download is complete, extract the contents of the ZIP file.
3. Move the extracted MongoDB shell folder to the MongoDB installation folder located in the C drive. This will ensure that both the MongoDB server and MongoDB shell are in the same place for easy access.
4. Make sure that you add the path bin folder of both the MongoDB server and shell to the environmental variables. Here's how to do it:

   - Open the Start menu and search for "environment variables."
   - Click on "Edit the system environment variables."
   - In the System Properties window, click on the "Environment Variables" button.
   - In the "System variables" section, locate the "Path" variable and click on "Edit."
   - Add a new entry with the path to the MongoDB server's bin folder (only if hadn't done this step before).
   - Add a new entry with the path to the MongoDB shell's bin folder.
   - Click "OK" to save the changes.
5. Open a new command prompt and run the following command:

   ```bash
   mongosh
   ```

When you run this command, you may encounter an error indicating that "C:/data/db/" is not found. (I faced this issue too!)

6. To resolve this issue, open the C drive in File Explorer and create a folder named "data". Inside the "data" folder, create another folder named "db". This is the default data directory used by MongoDB.

Now, to connect the MongoDB shell with the running server (mongod), follow these steps:

7. After creating the "data" and "db" folders, run the following command in the command prompt:

   ```bash
   mongod
   ```

This time, the MongoDB server (i.e., mongod) should run successfully without any errors. Important Point: Please do not close the mongod window. If you close this window, your server will stop working and will no longer be able to connect with the mongo shell.

8. Finally, to start the MongoDB shell, open a new command prompt and run the following command:

   ```bash
   mongosh
   ```

The MongoDB server and shell should now start without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Command changed in the new versions of mongo

```
mongodb --version // to check version of mongo
mongosh  // to starting the shell.
```

Comment: Your Answer is correct, I installed the latest version 70.5, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you already include the mondoDb bin folder into your environments, make sure you are running the command `mongos` not `mongo`. It was my issue!

***My mongos version*** v7.0.2

Answer (score -1):

for mongoDb v5.0 and latest use mongosh instead of mongo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hGnX.png)

Answer (score -1):

I face same Problem When i installed mongoDB Version(6.0).
I'm following some tutorial,
and use this command ["C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin\mongo.exe" --version] to check the version of mongoDB.
So I'm not able to move further because i got stuck here.Then i find a solution

Steps
1.open environment variable
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv7P4.png)
2.click on environment variable button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtAtl.jpg)
3.copy a path on c drive
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTccR.jpg)
4.click on edit button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG6G4.jpg)
5.paste a path on variable name and variable value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWIs8.jpg)
6.then click ok
7.afther use this command to check version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Nbno.jpg)

Comment: Formatting would improve readability

Answer (score -1):

"mongo" or "mongosh" didn't work in my case. I am using version 6.0 and while trying out the commands, I found "mongod" did the work.

Answer (score -2):

I was also getting the same error on version 6.0 after that I downgraded to version 5 , the issue resolved but make sure you have edited the environment variable and at the end of your path put '\

Answer (score -3):

Change the Version to 5.something, It will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Use version 5.0 because here you will get mongo.exe in your bin folder
[Bin folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0UUP.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).