# MongoDB 6.0 upgrade unable to log in: mongosh and mongo do not exist

Tags: mongodb

I've upgraded from mongodb version 5 to version 6. I'm running windows 10.

Once I upgraded to version 6 my system no longer recognizes the mongo commands I usually use to log in:

```
PS C:\Users\bluet> mongosh
mongosh : The term 'mongosh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ mongosh
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mongosh:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\bluet> mongo
mongo : The term 'mongo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ mongo
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mongo:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I checked the bin directory where mongo is installed and I don't see `mongo` or `mongosh` listed:

```
PS C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin> ls


    Directory: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----          7/5/2022   6:40 PM           1558 InstallCompass.ps1
-a----         7/24/2022   4:12 PM            577 mongod.cfg
-a----          7/5/2022   8:15 PM       55887872 mongod.exe
-a----          7/5/2022   8:15 PM      832090112 mongod.pdb
-a----          7/5/2022   8:22 PM       34573824 mongos.exe
-a----          7/5/2022   8:22 PM      464392192 mongos.pdb
```

I am not sure why the commands aren't there, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0/73084403#73084403

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Comment: Yes, it certainly does. Thank you! I have it working now.