# Cannot connect to MongoDB through visual studio Terminal

Tags: mongodb

A couple of days ago everything worked perfectly, but now I cannot connect to any Database I launch. I first create a folder, I open an integrated terminal and write 'mongod --dbpath [path]', and that seems to work
I then open a second terminal and simply write 'mongo' as usual, and I get the following error (Google translated from Spanish)

*mongo : The term 'mongo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check if you typed the name correctly or if you included a path,
check that this path is correct and try again.*

*Online: 1 Character: 1*

*mongo*

*CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (mongo:String) [], CommandNotFoundException*

*FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException*

My path is set up correctly and I have no idea what changed for this to happen.

Comment: The program `mongo` was deprecated two years ago. The replacement is `mongosh`. Check if you have that program installed on your system.

Comment: I have tried updating to the 6.0.0, it doesn't work

Comment: What does not work? The CLI tools are not included with 6.0. You must install them separately.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0/73084403#73084403