# MongoDB installation problem(mongo.exe not downloaded with the setup)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I downloaded 6th version of MongoDB. But after installing the setup, mongo.exe file is missing. I tried with both msi and zip installation, still mongo.exe file is missing. I installed other versions also ..but facing similar problem. Please help

Comment: install it through docker

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB v6.0.0 **doesn't ship** with a **MongoDB shell** i.e. **mongo.exe**

you can **download** the **mongo shell[Mongosh]** form [here](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell?jmp=docs) also here's the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/install/) on how to install it

**or**, just **check** this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxMAhi8sxoE) it will **explain** to you **how to install** it

Also, try installing **v5.0.10** from the [MongoDB website](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community) it **has** mongo.exe