# after adding path in enviroment variables why i am getting this error?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

''mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'

my path is:  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

It will not work as there is no **mongo.exe** file in that **specified** **path** as MongoDB v6.0.0 **doesn't ship** with a **MongoDB shell** i.e. **mongo** that you're trying run in cmd

you can **download** the **mongo shell[Mongosh]** form [here](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell?jmp=docs) also here's the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/install/) on how to install it

**or**, just **check** this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxMAhi8sxoE) it will **explain** to you **how to install** it

[edited]

###### also if you want you can see the web address and port when you run mongod command

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr5Hm.png)