# Mongo.exe file does not exist\

Tags: mongodb, mern

I installed community version of mongodb on windows 11, but mongo.exe is missing inside my bin directory. and I'm unable to use mongo shell. ?

Comment: Mongo shell is not included in server package anymore, you have to download separately.

Comment: The MongoDB Shell (mongosh) is not installed with MongoDB Server. You need to follow the mongosh installation instructions to download and install mongosh separately. follow this link : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)