# How to run mongo/mongosh command through vs code terminal?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I am a newbie to mongoDB, I have installed the mongoDb and when I am trying to run mongo command through VS code terminal, it is showing error like

```
mongo: command not found
```

I have mongo installed in my C drive vs code also is in C drive but the project is in E drive.
Is this a problem?

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Comment: 1) Which version of MongoDB is installed? 2) mongo was deprecated several years ago. Download and install mongosh. 3) If you have installed mongosh, is the location set in the PATH environment variable? Edit your question with details.