# "mongod" works to connect do database but i cant reach the shell because "mongo" doesn't work

Tags: mongodb

[image: Mongo and mongod at cmd]
I can not access the mongodb shell but I can access the port 27017 after I type mongod in cmd, also mongo doesnt work but mongod does. The path in environment variables is correct which is C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin but there is no .exe called mongo only mongod and mongos I want to access to mongodb shell

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)