# mongosh is a valid command but mongo is not found

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have mongodb community 6.0.0 installed.

The command `mongo` is not found.

The command `mongosh` is working.

```
mongosh --version
1.5.4
```

Comment: Why do you need the legacy `mongo` shell? The new mongosh shell should provide all the same functionality. The code for the new shell lives here: https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongosh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [official document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongo),

> The `mongo` shell has been deprecated in MongoDB v5.0. The replacement is `mongosh`.

As you are using MongoDB v6.0, `mongo` is deprecated in your version.