# how to connect to the mongoDB through command line?

Tags: mongodb, docker

I set up mongoDb via docker:

```
docker run -d --name mongodb \
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root \
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass \
-p 27017:27017 mongo
```

- `docker ps`:

> CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                      >NAMES
> c2d699cbd1b1   mongo     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago   Up 2 hours   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   mongodb

How to establish the connection to the mongoDB if I haven't mongo locally?

`C:\Users\HP>mongo`:

> 'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongosh is a valid command but mongo is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73377384/mongosh-is-a-valid-command-but-mongo-is-not-found)

Comment: You need to install the `mongo` CLI tool locally.  There are ways around this using `docker run` to launch a temporary container with the CLI, but this is inconvenient in a couple of ways.

Comment: As @DavidMaze said you need something locally, or CLI or maybe a UI tool like JB's DataGrip or [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass). These two are only a few examples there are many out there.

Comment: @matic1123, actually - all what I need - to understand that I can establish connection from the spring-boot. At all. May be you can give me tips according this issue? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75288344/datasourcebeancreationexception-failed-to-determine-a-suitable-driver-class-ho/75288859#75288859

Comment: Still have: `URL must start with 'jdbc'`