# DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class. How to establish connection to the mongoDB from spring?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker

I try to implement the spring-boot project with mongoDB.

The mongoDB isn't installed locally - I use docker image for this task.
So:

- `docker run -d --name mongodb -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -p 27017:27017`

docker image installed successfully and I able to enter into docker shell with

`docker exec -it {conteinerId} bash`

Now, I try to execute spring-boot application.

- application.properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=proxy_db
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.username=root
spring.data.mongodb.password=pass
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

- pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.task</groupId>
    <artifactId>task</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>crud</name>
    <description>User CRUD endpoints</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.6.6</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

After launching I received warning:

> 2023-01-30 19:53:41.941  WARN 12208 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

And as result, error:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

> Description:
>
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
> no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

As I understand - the spring can't establish the connection with the database.

- So, how to correctly manage MongoDB in the spring-boot + docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong property names, eg url, hence `"Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified."`

Try these:

```
spring.datasource.url = mongodb://localhost:27017/proxy_db
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password
```

Optionally you may need this:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mongodb.Mongo
```

Also there appear to be missing/incorrect dependencies:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
But in this case, I receive `IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mongodb.Mongo` without `spring.datasource.driver-class-name`, and `IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mongodb.Mongo` when I added this option

Comment: I believe my answer is correct for the question asked. That’ issue something else related to dependencies, very likely this - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver.

Comment: Resolved.
What I did: I added your options, added dependency that you mentioned, but also I removed `spring-data-starter-jpa` dependency since I use `-starter-mongodb` also and they do not have to be used both.
Thanks