# BadValue: error: no args for --configdb try 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin\mongos.exe --help' for more information

Tags: mongodb

I finished installing MongoDB and I am trying the command `$ mongo` and I keep getting an error:

`BadValue: error: no args for --configdb try 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin\mongos.exe --help' for more information`

Comment: Have you followed the [installation tutorial for Windows](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)?

Comment: Are you sure you run `mongo` or `mongosh` and not `mongos`? `mongos` is the [Router](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/) in a sharded cluster

Comment: it looks like you messed up mongo and mongos

Comment: To clarify, you are running `mongo` and not `$ mongo`, right? Instructions often include the dollar sign, but it is not to be typed - it is your existing command prompt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have set up the config server as a standalone process and you might have to use a replicaset instead.

This might help:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/sharding/

Your command will look something like this:
mongos --configdb replsetname/localhost:27010 --port 27011

But if you are trying to use the mongoDb shell then you might have to download it separately. They do not bundle the shell together as they used to before. So you have to download mongosh as a zip and extract the contents of the "bin" folder to the "bin" folder where you have installed mongo. Then you can use the MongoDB shell(mongosh.exe).

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with the same problem just download mongosh https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell and then move all files from its bin to mongodb bin which was already present and then press mongosh and you will be directed to its shell

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows user:**

I simply fixed this issue by installing [mongoshell](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/atlascli) separately from MongoDB official website.

Follow this below procedure:

1. Download [Mongo_Shell](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/atlascli) from from [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com) official website.
2. Once Downloaded, Extract the files and go into the bin folder. Copy all the files from bin folder. Paste all these files in **C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\7.0\bin** (you version name might be different).
3. Now do not forget to add C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\7.0\bin this path in your windows environmental variables.
4. To do that go to your settings and search "**env**" and go to "**Edit the System environment variables option**" A window will pop up, find "**Environment Variable**" option.
5. Now find "**Path**" keyword and click on "**Edit**" and then Click on "**New**" and paste  "**C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\7.0\bin**" your path and click **ok**.
6. Now go to windows power shell or command prompt and run **`mongod.exe`** (For running the server) and **`mongosh.exe`** (for connecting shell to the server).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mongos shell separately. It can be downloaded as a zip file you need to extract it to the program files. Then add the location of mongos.exe to the vim.
If you face any difficulty in adding the path to vim use this [link](https://medium.com/@LondonAppBrewery/how-to-download-install-mongodb-on-windows-4ee4b3493514).

Make sure to change the version in the path example, mine will look like this.

```
alias mongod="/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/6.0/bin/mongod.exe"
alias mongos="/c/Program\ Files/mongosh-1.6.1-win32-x64/mongosh-1.6.1-win32-x64/bin/mongos.exe"
```

Don't make an exact copy of this. Change the path according to your setup and add these values in vim and close it using

```
:wq!
```

Use the provided link for handling the vim.

Comment: this is completely wrong, mongos and mongosh are different binaries

Answer (score 0):

Use the command **"mongosh"** instead.

The legacy Mongo shell that ran with the **mongo** command was deprecated in MongoDB 5.0 and removed in MongoDB 6.0.

Answer (score -1):

The following procedure might solve your problem:

1. Install the shell from [MongoDB website](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell)
2. Then copy all the files from the bin directory of MongoDB Shell (mongosh)
3. And paste them into directory Mongodb/server/version/bin
4. Then change the alias using vim to

   `alias mongod="/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/6.0/bin/mongod.exe"`

   `alias mongos="/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/6.0/bin/mongosh.exe"`

Comment: this is completely wrong, mongos and mongosh are different binaries