# mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: mongodb

[mongo is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs5W9.png)[mongodb is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgPNq.png)I'm encountering these errors after having installed mongodb using a tutorial and after having tried the edit environment variables fix.[I've edited the environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q33eX.png) The mongosh keyword is recognized when I type it in in the command line but mongo and mongodb aren't. Mongod results in something I'm not certain it should be resulting in.[is this expected?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sq7k.png) I noticed that the number of files available in my bin folder which is where mongodb is installed is less than that of others that I've seen.[this is my bin folder with less files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQIbG.png)  I also noticed that  after installing mongodb, the mongo compass didn't auto install. I did that manually. How can I overcome these errors and start using mongodb?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongod` is the binary that runs the database. It has many flags, [documented here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongod). The output you see is expected. You will often run this in the background via `--fork` and send the output to a logfile.

`mongo` is the legacy shell that is [deprecated](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/reference/program/mongo/) as of 6.0 and no longer ships.

`mongosh` is the [new shell](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/) that should provide all the same functionality as the legacy shell.

`mongodb` there is no binary with this name.

If you are trying to connect to MongoDB Atlas or an existing database, you should not need to run `mongod` yourself.