# Mongo is not installed via Homebrew (MacOS Monterey)

Tags: mongodb, homebrew, macos-monterey

I am trying to use MongoDB on MacOS Monterey, but it does not seem to work. I've installed it via Homebrew, and the

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/bin/mongo
```

is missing.

`brew list mongodb-community@6.0`

returns:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/bin/install_compass
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/bin/mongod
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/bin/mongos
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/MPL-2
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first use:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

Then use:

```
brew install mongodb-community@6.0
```

This is documented on this MongoDB page:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/