# When installing mongoDB I was able to run mongod --version on my cmd but not mongo --version

Tags: mongodb

Does anyone know how to fix this?
For my installation process what I did was simply install mongoDB and then I added the bin location to my environment variables path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Comment: Have you installed MongoDB Database Tools? they include "mongo" for use in the terminal: https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools

Comment: Download from here: https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell

Comment: I figured out what was the problem after version 6.0.0 mongo.exe does not get installed and you have to manually install the new MongoDB shell which is called mongosh then you have to add its path to ur system variables and then run mongosh --version to see if it got installed