# Cant run the command "mongo" and "mongod" - MongoDB Community Edition can’t install on Macbook

Tags: database, mongodb, terminal

I followed the steps in the documentation of Mongo here;
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#std-label-osx-prereq

I use Macbook Air 2017 (Intel).

However, somehow I cannot run the commands like “mongo” or “mongod” successfully.

When I command “mongo”, terminal says zsh: command not found mongo.

When I try to run “mongod” I get this very long error message that I attach with the post.

[Screenshot of the error I get when I run "mongod"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKDuo.png)

Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Comment: Please post the code or error into your question, not an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.