# Mongo DB - bash: mongo: command not found

Tags: database, mongodb

So I have been learning about databases and I'm new to it. In my udemy course the video was outdated for the installation of MngoDB version 6.0.1. The video instructor showed a way to install it using the vim editor. However it didn't work for me. Then I discovered that many people are going through the same problem and a guy told a solution to delete the file created with vim and instead use "system environment variable". I edited the path by adding a new one in which I did exactly as the guy mentioned to specify the 'bin' folder inside mongoDB in the Program files. And when I tried to run the 'mongod' command inside hyper I got this at the last line.

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-09T10:05:27.885+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   
"ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
```

The instructor did mention that I should see something like "Waiting for connections at port 27017". However the last line in hyper doesn't explicitly mention it in one line, but I think that's fine. Because the instructor was using a mac and I am using a Windows device. Now here comes the main error. When I open a new tab in Hyper and type 'mongo', I get this error

```
$ mongo
bash: mongo: command not found
```

I've researched a lot on stackoverflow but nothing helped me in the end. However I can provide with something that might help in figuring out the solution. Here's something unusual that I noticed. The 'bin' folder in C:/ProgramFiles/MongoDB/Server/6.0 seems to contain very few files. It has only 2 .exe applications namely - 'mongod.exe' & 'mongos.exe'. There is no 'mongo.exe' that my instructor has on her computer. I think this might be the root of the problem, however I'm not sure. also there are other files that seem to be missing. But I would like to mention that I've not tampered the files even once since I've installed them from the setup. I hope this is enough for you guys to solve this. Please help me.

Comment: Whoever convinced you that you could "learn databases" by watching video tutorials without going through all the prerequisites (Unix, the shell, a couple of programming languages, data structures, freaking Vim, etc.) should be the one(s) helping you get out of the pit they dug for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Comment: @romainl Well I don't think I explicitly mentioned that I don't know any programming languages, or any of the stuff you think I can't do. I know how to use shell, command line, react, bootstrap, angular, javascript, html, css. So yeah please only cooment if you can help me.

Comment: @dododo Thanks man! Well I actually figured it out before I looked at your answer but it's pretty much the same solution I guess. I installed mongosh and it worked like a charm.