# mongo is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: mongodb, file

I have installed MongoDB with its compass and respective `mongosh` on two separate computers one with version 5 (since I read that from similar posts to this that the older version would not have that sort of issue) and other with version 6. I followed all the steps from serveral videos and posts on how to properly install.

I have installed MongoDB as a service.

I have set it's path on system enviroment variables copying the location of their respective executables.

I am unable to make them function on my cmd.

[image: here's is an image]

I would apreciate the help.^^

Comment: "I am unable to make them function on my cmd."  What command are you using and what is the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Comment: it's unclear what and where doesn't work for you