# After setting variable showing this error again 'mongo is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mern

I have installed mongodb and put a path in environment variable.When i use cmd it still throwing error which is 'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cskvm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLG8w.png)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Answer (score 2):

The `mongo` executable is [deprecated and no longer available in 6.0](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/6.0-compatibility/#legacy-mongo-shell-removed).

Keep in mind this is just the shell, `mongod` is the binary that runs the database.

`mongosh` is the new shell.

Look in `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin` to see the binaries that exist.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error and managed to resolve it by taking the following steps:

1. I visited the official MongoDB website (https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell) to download the MongoDB Shell.
2. After installing the MongoDB Shell, I added the path to the bin directory of the MongoDB Shell installation to the system's 'Path' environment variable.
3. To ensure the changes took effect, I closed all the active Command Prompt windows.
4. I opened a new Command Prompt window and executed the command 'Mongod' to start the MongoDB server.
5. Following that, I opened another Command Prompt window and executed the command 'mongosh'.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure MongoDB is installed on your system.
2. Add the MongoDB bin directory to your system's PATH environment variable:
   Windows: Edit PATH in Environment Variables to include MongoDB bin directory.
   Linux/Mac: Edit shell profile file (e.g., ~/.bashrc) to add MongoDB bin    directory to PATH.
   Open a new terminal/command prompt and type mongo to check if the error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

## **Legacy `mongo` Shell Removed**

The `mongo` shell is **removed** from MongoDB 6.0.

### The replacement is **`mongosh`**.

[Legacy mongo Shell Removed](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/6.0-compatibility/#legacy-mongo-shell-removed)