# how to connect to mongdb locally

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building this webapp and was using mongodb atlas but got some really slow connection times so decided to try and build my database locally. But now I'm running into a bunch of problems connecting to the local install. I am using mongodb 6 and mongoDB compass on windows 10. Whenever I try to run the mongod.exe file I get this mess of an ouput.

```
C:\Users\carjames>mongod
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:18.711-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.032-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.034-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.036-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.036-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.036-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.036-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.037-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":23072,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/data/db/","architecture":"64-bit","host":"CSCO-W-PF363H2F"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.038-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.038-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.2","gitVersion":"94fb7dfc8b974f1f5343e7ea394d0d9deedba50e","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.038-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 19044)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.038-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.041-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=7531M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,remove=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=2000),statistics_log=(wait=0),json_output=(error,message),verbose=[recovery_progress:1,checkpoint_progress:1,compact_progress:1,backup:0,checkpoint:0,compact:0,evict:0,history_store:0,recovery:0,rts:0,salvage:0,tiered:0,timestamp:0,transaction:0,verify:0,log:0],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.188-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":147}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.188-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.219-04:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.220-04:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22140,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This server is bound to localhost. Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.220-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"admin.system.version","uuidDisposition":"provided","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"9e26c9cf-f4a3-4c3c-bee0-5015b66bf787"}},"options":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"9e26c9cf-f4a3-4c3c-bee0-5015b66bf787"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.241-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"collectionUUID":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"9e26c9cf-f4a3-4c3c-bee0-5015b66bf787"}},"namespace":"admin.system.version","index":"_id_","ident":"index-1-3551700052986010320","collectionIdent":"collection-0-3551700052986010320","commitTimestamp":null}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.241-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":20459,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting featureCompatibilityVersion","attr":{"newVersion":"6.0"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.245-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5853300, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"current featureCompatibilityVersion value","attr":{"featureCompatibilityVersion":"6.0","context":"setFCV"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.249-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915702, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Updated wire specification","attr":{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true},"newSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":17,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":17,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.250-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915702, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Updated wire specification","attr":{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":17,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":17,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true},"newSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":17,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":17,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.250-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5853300, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"current featureCompatibilityVersion value","attr":{"featureCompatibilityVersion":"6.0","context":"startup"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.253-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":5071100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing temp directory"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.258-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.749-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"C:/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.754-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"local.startup_log","uuidDisposition":"generated","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"91b66a1a-ecea-4937-80a3-de0163c174c3"}},"options":{"capped":true,"size":10485760}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.774-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"collectionUUID":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"91b66a1a-ecea-4937-80a3-de0163c174c3"}},"namespace":"local.startup_log","index":"_id_","ident":"index-3-3551700052986010320","collectionIdent":"collection-2-3551700052986010320","commitTimestamp":null}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.775-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigReplicationDisabled","oldState":"ConfigPreStart"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.775-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.790-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"config.system.sessions","uuidDisposition":"generated","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"fb6f40f6-0fd3-4d11-a4a7-1fb80aecde39"}},"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.792-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20712,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions reap interval","attr":{"error":"NamespaceNotFound: config.system.sessions does not exist"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.794-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.794-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.828-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"collectionUUID":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"fb6f40f6-0fd3-4d11-a4a7-1fb80aecde39"}},"namespace":"config.system.sessions","index":"_id_","ident":"index-5-3551700052986010320","collectionIdent":"collection-4-3551700052986010320","commitTimestamp":null}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.829-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"collectionUUID":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"fb6f40f6-0fd3-4d11-a4a7-1fb80aecde39"}},"namespace":"config.system.sessions","index":"lsidTTLIndex","ident":"index-6-3551700052986010320","collectionIdent":"collection-4-3551700052986010320","commitTimestamp":null}}
```

and when i try to just run the mongo command in terminal I get

```
C:\Users\carjames>mongo
'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Even thought I added the bin file with mongod to my path variable.

I see it says its listening on localhost somehwere towards the bottom of the output so I checked the services and mongodb server is running. I can also create db and collectoins in compass. But when I try to connect to the database in node with mongoose nothing happens.

```
async function mongoConnect(){
    let db
    try {
        db = await mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost:27017/barton-bot-db`)
        debug(`Connected`)
        console.log('connected')
        return db
    } catch (err) {
        debug(err)
    }
}

(async ()=>{
    console.log('test')
    await mongoConnect()

})()


module.exports = mongoConnect
```

I got this error after waiting a few minutes for the err msg to log.

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (c:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\Barton-Bot-Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:824:32)
    at c:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\Barton-Bot-Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:380:10
    at c:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\Barton-Bot-Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (c:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\Barton-Bot-Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (c:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\Barton-Bot-Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1225:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (c:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\Barton-Bot-Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:379:20)
    at mongoConnect (c:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\Barton-Bot-Backend\utils\db\mongoConnect.js:10:29)
    at c:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\Barton-Bot-Backend\utils\db\mongoConnect.js:21:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\Barton-Bot-Backend\utils\db\mongoConnect.js:23:3) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

Please help!!

Comment: what error it is throwing, like can you console log the error

Comment: Just in case, are you actually calling the "mongoConnect()" function somewhere in your code? Maybe that's why 'nothing happens'

Comment: Yea I am that just a function I import to connect to db in another file @MiguelJara

Comment: It doesn't log any error when I run mongoConnect() @MohamedAnserAli

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens?

Comment: I guess he means by not connecting

Comment: Actually @MohamedAnserAli I did get an error, I just wasn't waiting long enough for it to log to the console. See my most recent edit, pls.

Comment: This looks suspicious: `::1:27017`.  Google responds with [this developer forum link](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/econnrefused-27017/131911)

Comment: You have two errors. For the first error `'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0

Comment: The mongod output is normal, is says `"Waiting for connections"`, i.e. it is up and running. Do you close the window before you try to connect with mode.js? That will stop the mongod service, of course and you cannot connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

If I may answer with a nonanswer, what's the purpose of this exercise?

The "*mess of an output*" you described is standard operational output logged by the `mongod` process. It is one of the aspects that comes along with managing a database system yourself. It always contains very helpful information, in this particular case it contains the following warnings:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.219-04:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-30T15:12:20.220-04:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22140,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This server is bound to localhost. Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
```

When managing a system yourself, it's very important to pay attention to configurations and details like these. Each of these are something you'll want to learn about and be sure to properly setup in order to run your environment successfully.  The first is warning you that you'll want to configure appropriate access control on your system which is critically important for the safety of your data. The second one is alerting you to networking components of the current configuration, which could actually be related to the connection problem that you've described (as Compass and your node app may be attempting to connect to the system using different interfaces).

Ultimately the database will have to be running somewhere in order for your web application to interact with it. You can certainly work to learn about how to properly configure the system and work through problems like this (which this community can assist with given appropriately framed and researched questions), or you could pivot to better understand and resolve the original problem you had. Fixing a slow connection time problem once may be more effective long term than attempting to manage the entire system yourself.