# how do i rid off this error "bash: mongo: command not found"

Tags: mongodb

I'm using docker to connect to MongoDB it worked fine but suddenly stop working when trying to connect to the mongo shell

this is the error I get

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS          PORTS                      NAMES
736853fcaa64   mongo-express   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   21 hours ago   Up 47 seconds   0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp     mongo-express
379274f50285   mongo           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   21 hours ago   Up 52 seconds   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   mongodb
PS C:\Windows\System32> docker exec -it 379274f50285 bash
root@379274f50285:/# mongo mongodb://localhost:27017 -u rootuser -p rootpass
**bash: mongo: command not found**
root@379274f50285:/#
```

Comment: which server version?

Comment: I think you should add the mongo folder path to the environment variables( globally ), so it can be accessed from anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The output you've provided suggests that the docker container was created recently (`21` hours before posting). My impression of your question is that things were working fine before that change and have not been working since.

My suspicion is that the container that you are using has MongoDB `6.0` (probably `6.0.2` specifically, but that's beside the point). As @dododo was probably alluding to with the question in the comments, the major version here is important. As of version `6.0`, the legacy `mongo` utility (which was deprecated in `5.0`) is no longer packaged and shipped with the server. This would definitely describe the `mongo: command not found` error that you are experiencing. @dododo answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73084403/20042973).

How to resolve this depends on exactly what you're trying to do which I don't think we have enough information to advise on. Options probably include replacing the image with a `5.0` version or installing one of the shells (either legacy `mongo` or the newer `mongosh`) on your current one (in a persistent manner).