# Unable to start mongodb after installation on centos 7

Tags: mongodb, shell, centos7

I tried to install Mongodb following steps below:

I Added repository on /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-6.0.repo

```
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-6.0.repo
```

Then saved this code:

```
[Mongodb-org-6.0]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/6.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Then install mongodb

```
yum repolist
sudo yum install mongodb-org
```

But when I try to start mongodb, I am getting the error below

```
sudo systemctl start mongod

Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

"systemctl status mongod.service" showing logs blow

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-10-02 09:10:00 EDT; 22s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 2849 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=14)
  Process: 2846 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2843 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2840 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 02 09:10:00 paut.toltechativ.net systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
Oct 02 09:10:00 paut.toltechativ.net mongod[2849]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Oct 02 09:10:00 paut.toltechativ.net mongod[2849]: forked process: 2851
Oct 02 09:10:00 paut.toltechativ.net mongod[2849]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with 14
Oct 02 09:10:00 paut.toltechativ.net mongod[2849]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
Oct 02 09:10:00 paut.toltechativ.net systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=14
Oct 02 09:10:00 paut.toltechativ.net systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
Oct 02 09:10:00 paut.toltechativ.net systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Oct 02 09:10:00 paut.toltechativ.net systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
```

"journalctl -xe" show logs below

```
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mongod.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Oct 02 09:12:20 paut.toltechativ.net systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Oct 02 09:12:20 paut.toltechativ.net systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
Oct 02 09:12:20 paut.toltechativ.net polkitd[2621]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3152:8289672425 (system bus name :1.2780728, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/A
Oct 02 09:12:20 paut.toltechativ.net sudo[3150]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Oct 02 09:12:24 paut.toltechativ.net kernel: Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=em1 OUT= MAC=10:98:36:a1:40:31:2c:21:31:8c:f0:80:08:00 SRC=183.136.225.42 DST=173.249.159.44 LEN=44 TOS=0x08 PREC=
```

And "cat /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" show this:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-02T11:48:39.487-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-02T11:48:39.490-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-02T11:48:39.492-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-02T11:48:39.493-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-02T11:48:39.503-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-02T11:48:39.503-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-02T11:48:39.503-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-02T11:48:39.503-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-02T11:48:39.503-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":23047,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongo","architecture":"64-bit","host":"paut.toltechativ.net"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-02T11:48:39.504-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.2","gitVersion":"94fb7dfc8b974f1f5343e7ea394d0d9deedba50e","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"rhel70","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-02T11:48:39.504-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) ","version":"Kernel 3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.x86_64"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-02T11:48:39.504-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017},"processManagement":{"fork":true,"pidFilePath":"/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid","timeZoneInfo":"/usr/share/zoneinfo"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongo","journal":{"enabled":true}},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-02T11:48:39.504-04:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-02T11:48:39.504-04:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":1125}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-02T11:48:39.504-04:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Comment: What does the `mongod` log file say?

Comment: @user20042973 just added that log to my initial question

Comment: Great. Should be lots of duplicate questions on this site about `mongod` having (permission) issues with unlinking the socket file. I'd recommend searching based on that

Comment: @user20042973 removed the socket with "rm -f /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock", and was able to start mongodb. But when trying to run mongodb with "mongod" command, I amgetting this error: "Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."

Comment: That's just an informative message rather than an error.  Sounds like the process is running

Comment: @user20042973 I want to be able run mongo commands.
For some reason, when I try "mongo" it give me "-bash: mongo: command not found"

Comment: That is a totally unrelated problem.  Please search this site for that error message and you'll find out how to handle it. In short - `mongo` no longer comes with the database as of 6.0 which you are running - you should download the MongoDB Shell instead

Comment: Regarding your second problem see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0

Comment: File `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` could be left if mongod was crashed and not shut down properly. After removing it, usually solved the problem.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks for the help. I think I have a last problem. I can't find "mongodb.so" in extension directory and so it didn't show in "phpinfo()" even that I added "extension=mongodb.so" to php.ini. Should I manually move "mongodb.so" to extensions directory?

Comment: That's really completely different and related to PHP. Please open a new question for it. Note, for PHP you have two drivers. The low level driver "MongoDB PHP Driver" and the high level "MongoDB PHP Library". Don't mix them up.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks bro. I just created a new thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73940614/handling-of-mongodb-when-moving-from-php-7-2-to-php-8-1