# Mongodb shell command and container gives as unknown

Tags: mongodb

I'm creating a mongodb container with this command:

```
docker run --name mongo -p 27017:27017  -d mongo mongod
```

And to have remote access I do the following command:

```
docker exec -it mongo bash
```

but when I try to run the `show dbs` command and it gives this error:
`bash: show: command not found.` Is there any client as a workbench? and what am i doing wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Comment: the above will be the answer if you use a server 60 or higher