# mongodb installation in pc

Tags: mongodb, installation, mongo-shell

I install mongodp from its web but when its complete its not showing anything i can follow my teacher but in c mongodb 6.0 bin mongodb its not opened but in mongosh its work proper it show the version of mongodb and version of mongosh and show database als but i want to follow my teacher so it is necessary to open from bin. plz  help please.

i want to open mongodb from bin but its not opened from bin but its work properly from mongosh. iwant to follow my teacher.
i reinstall mongodb and also delte from c but its not working. i repair it mongodb install repair option but the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

mongo binary is legacy shell and no longer shipped with server binaries. See for [details](https://mongo%20binary%20is%20legacy%20shell%20and%20no%20longer%20shipped%20with%20server%20binaries.%20See%20for%20details:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0/73084403#73084403.%20If%20y). If you, for some reason, need it, you should download a server binaries < 6.0, like 5.0.14 from [here](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community). And just copy mongo binary from there (without the rest server binaries).