# Warning: No available formula with the name "mongodb-community@6.0"

Tags: mongodb, command-line-interface, mern

Trying to install mongodb server on my mac using Brew but getting this error.
[image]

Updated my brew to latest version, still getting this error.
Command i used:
`brew install mongodb-community@6.0`

Comment: This one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Here is the solution which I found out. I am using mac os on intel processor.

I first run

```
rm -fr $(brew --repo homebrew/core)
```

then

```
brew tap homebrew/core
```

then

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

then installed it

```
brew install mongodb-community@6.0
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I've been trying to install mongodb for over a month now, but all the tutorials I found were for earlier versions and required me to create a `/data/db` directory which is no longer allowed in current versions of macOS. I only had to run `brew tap mongodb/brew` and the `install` command though, without needing to delete the `homebrew/core` directory.

Comment: For the latest version please check the MongoDB website and change the mongodb-community@6.0 to whatever latest version and replace 6.0 with the latest version number for e.g 6.2 or 6.2 ...