# i cant run mongo.exe from cmd

Tags: database, mongodb

every time I run mongod.exe from cmd I get the following message on my screen
[image: cmd screen]

I'm a beginner in this so I really don't know what it means

I haven't seen anything on the web describing this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots (the most relevant part is even cut off), use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 0):

You have three questions.

- Cannot run `mongo.exe` - See [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)
- Excessive output when you run `mongod.exe`

Install MongoDB as service. Create a [configuration file](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/) (a default file should be created at `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin\mongod.cfg` while installation) and create the service with

```
mongod.exe --install "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin\mongod.cfg"
```

Then your MongoDB starts automatically at boot time.

- I haven't seen anything describing the log format - See [Log Messages](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/log-messages/)