# MongoDB : mongo, mongos, mongosh, mongod

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

What are the key differences among :

1. mongo
2. mongos
3. mongosh
4. mongod

I've tried many websites but didn't get clear explanations for these.

Answer (score 3):

Server side binaries:

- `mongos` is a router for sharding. It will be used if your server is configured as sharded.
- `mongod` is a particular server. Can be used alone (not recommended for production) or as part of replica set.

Client side binaries:

- `mongo` is a legacy shell to query server
- `mongosh` is a modern shell to query server

Comment: In MongoDB installer package I got only mongos and mongod.
Now for running mongodb commands which one is recommended "mongo" or "mongosh" ?

Comment: mongosh, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0/73084403#73084403