# MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.44.22:27017 (Windows Server 2019/Windows 10)

Tags: mongodb, windows, mongosh

I installed:

- `MongoDB`  v7.0.5 as a service on the Windows Server 2019.
- `Mongosh` v2.1.5 on the Windows 10

But when trying to connect the MongoDB server on the Windows Server 2019 from the Windows 10 I receive the following error:

> MongoNetworkError: connect **ECONNREFUSED** 172.18.44.22:27017

I checked:

- MongoDB service is running
- The Windows Firewall is configured don't block port `27017` (in/out)

I checked a lot of posts on StackOverflow: most of these related to Linux, the rest  are describing solutions that don't help.

What might be problem?

---

When I launch `mongosh` locally on the Windows Server 2019 it is running without a problem.

Thanks

Comment: How do you ensure MongoDB service is running? `mongosh` is just a shell connecting to mongodb instance and does not implies the db service is running. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75823240/mongodb-mongo-mongos-mongosh-mongod for the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click on the service and have a look at "Path to Executable", should be something like `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\mongod.exe --config ...`

Have a look at the config file, most likely it contains these lines:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: localhost
```

Which means, the MongoDB listens to `localhost` and you can connect only from your local machine. To enable connections from other computers change it to

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true
```

and restart the service.