MongoDB v.3.2.11: Intersection of the range of multiple row values with object fields
This post is a continuation of the previous posts:

Intersection of the range of values
MongoDB - Intersection of the range of multiple row values
MongoDB: Intersection of the range of multiple row values with object fields

Suppose we have a mongodb collection with 6 columns in object field:

investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationFrom
investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationTo
investmentParameters.rentalYieldFrom
investmentParameters.rentalYieldTo
investmentParameters.occupancyRateFrom
investmentParameters.occupancyRateTo

Now I would like to select rows where range** *From / *To intersect with another ranges.
For example:
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    "investmentParameters": {
      "capitalAppreciationFrom": 30,
      "capitalAppreciationTo": 60,
      "rentalYieldFrom": 30,
      "rentalYieldTo": 60,
      "occupancyRateFrom": 30,
      "occupancyRateTo": 60
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    "investmentParameters": {
      "capitalAppreciationFrom": 17,
      "capitalAppreciationTo": 80,
      "rentalYieldFrom": 17,
      "rentalYieldTo": 80,
      "occupancyRateFrom": 17,
      "occupancyRateTo": 80
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    "investmentParameters": {
      "capitalAppreciationFrom": 27,
      "capitalAppreciationTo": 87,
      "rentalYieldFrom": 27,
      "rentalYieldTo": 87,
      "occupancyRateFrom": 27,
      "occupancyRateTo": 87
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 4,
    "investmentParameters": {
      "capitalAppreciationFrom": 23,
      "capitalAppreciationTo": 57,
      "rentalYieldFrom": 23,
      "rentalYieldTo": 57,
      "occupancyRateFrom": 23,
      "occupancyRateTo": 57
    }
  }
]

** - range in this case is:

value - from
values - from and to
value - to

So lets call our filter fields like this:

capitalAppreciationFilter which can be:


capitalAppreciationFilterFrom
capitalAppreciationFilterFrom + capitalAppreciationFilterTo
capitalAppreciationFilterTo


rentalYieldFilter which can be:


rentalYieldFilterFrom
rentalYieldFilterFrom + rentalYieldFilterTo
rentalYieldFilterTo


occupancyRateFilter which can be:


occupancyRateFilterFrom
occupancyRateFilterFrom + occupancyRateFilterTo
occupancyRateFilterTo

If we talk about fields in the DB, then we have the following correspondences with the filter:

investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationFrom - capitalAppreciationFilterFrom
investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationTo - capitalAppreciationFilterTo
investmentParameters.rentalYieldFrom - rentalYieldFilterFrom
investmentParameters.rentalYieldTo - rentalYieldFilterTo
investmentParameters.occupancyRateFrom - occupancyRateFilterFrom
investmentParameters.occupancyRateTo - occupancyRateFilterTo

We need to write queries that will select the intersections of ranges (not the range occurrences, but the intersection).
For example we take Object #1 and Condition #1:
occupancyRateFilterFrom - $gte: 30
rentalYieldFilterFrom - $gte: 20
rentalYieldFilterTo - $lte: 40

First range with from value - occupancyRateFilterFrom = $gte: 30 falls within the range of 30 to 60 (investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationFrom = 30 and investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationTo = 60). Next range with from + to values - rentalYieldFilterFrom = $gte: 20 / rentalYieldFilterTo = $lte: 40 intersects (is included in the range investmentParameters.rentalYieldFrom = 30 and investmentParameters.rentalYieldTo = 60) with the range from 30 to 60. Thus, the Object #1 gets into the selection. The same thing with the other objects - all get into the selection under current query conditions.
Also, if it may be important:
/# mongo --version                                                                                               
MongoDB version v3.2.11

We need to write queries that will select the intersections of ranges (not the range occurrences, but the intersection).
For example I will give you the conditions under which 4 objects should always be selected.
Condition #1
occupancyRateFilterFrom - $gte: 30
rentalYieldFilterFrom - $gte: 20
rentalYieldFilterTo - $lte: 40

Condition #2
occupancyRateFilterFrom - $gte: 27
rentalYieldFilterFrom - $gte: 20
rentalYieldFilterTo - $lte: 40

Condition #3
occupancyRateFilterFrom  - $gte: 37
rentalYieldFilterFrom - $gte: 20
rentalYieldFilterTo - $lte: 40

Condition #4
occupancyRateFilterFrom  - $gte: 40
rentalYieldFilterFrom - $gte: 20
rentalYieldFilterTo - $lte: 40

Under all these 4 conditions, 4 objects must always be selected.
Now I change occupancyRateFilterFrom - $lte: 16 so we have the condition:
occupancyRateFilterTo - $gte: 16
rentalYieldFilterFrom - $gte: 20
rentalYieldFilterTo - $lte: 40

then none of the 4 objects should be included in the query result.
Next we have the condition:
capitalAppreciationFilterFrom - $gte: 62
occupancyRateFilterFrom - $gte: 16
rentalYieldFilterFrom - $gte: 20
rentalYieldFilterTo - $lte: 40

As a result of the selection, we should see the following objects:

Object #2
Object #3

And of course, the sampling conditions can be combined:
occupancyRateFilterFrom - $gte: x
rentalYieldFilterFrom - $gte: x
rentalYieldFilterTo - $lte: x

occupancyRateFilterFrom - $gte: x
occupancyRateFilterTo - $lte: x
rentalYieldFilterFrom - $gte: x
rentalYieldFilterTo - $lte: x

capitalAppreciationFilterFrom - $gte: x
occupancyRateFilterFrom - $gte: x
occupancyRateFilterTo - $lte: x
rentalYieldFilterFrom - $gte: x
rentalYieldFilterTo - $lte: x

capitalAppreciationFilterFrom - $gte: x
capitalAppreciationFilterTo - $gte: x
occupancyRateFilterFrom - $gte: x
occupancyRateFilterTo - $lte: x
rentalYieldFilterFrom - $gte: x
rentalYieldFilterTo - $lte: x

capitalAppreciationFilterFrom - $gte: x

capitalAppreciationFilterTo - $gte: x

and so on ...
Each subsequent filter reduces the current selection, thereby narrowing the selection result.

Most likely just a typo or different data. I doubt it does not wotk (what so you mean by "does not work ") for all three variations. Why do you like to make it working on an ancient and unsupported version of MongoDB?



what so you mean by "does not work " I have empty results.



Why do you expect all documents for condition "investmentParameters.occupancyRateFrom": { $gte: 30 }? This condition is true only for the first document. Otherwise combine them with $or and $and - again you need to explain your requirements.

MongoDB shell version 8.0.0 does not exist. Legacy mongo shell mongo stopped at version 5.0.8. Successor is the mongosh where current version is 2.3.1



MongoDB shell version 8.0.0 does not exist What this: https://c2n.me/4lxWkV0.png?



Or the same from console: https://c2n.me/4lxWBDk.png?



You mixed the Mongo database and the mongo shell I don't quite understand what you're talking about. I wrote about the DB version, which I found out as db.version() or mongo --version. What does mongo shell have to do with it, I don't understand? I didn't say or write anything about mongo shell.



In your question you talk about the Mongo shell. And db.version() returns something different than mongo --version. Again, you mistake the mongo database and the mongo (legacy) shell.

I show you both db.version() and mongo --version and it's the same. So I still don't understand what a u talking about. Sorry. Please clarify the situation.

Legacy mongo shell mongo does not exist in version 8. And Mongo DB version 3.2 is outdated for almost 10 years. Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75823240/mongodb-mongo-mongos-mongosh-mongod

Thanks for the link - I'll definitely study it.

You should open a new question. Your initial question was "I have a query which works fine on Mongo version A but fails on Mongo version B" Now it became completely different.



Are they combined by OR or AND Are you sure you understand how filtering works? Each subsequent filter reduces the current selection, thereby narrowing the selection result.





And what is your question? We need to write queries that will select the intersections of ranges (not the range occurrences, but the intersection). It's wroted in the post.





Conditions are still rubbish! Post updated. Still not clear?



Maybe this will be useful for someone. At the moment I have such solutions.
Filter - From: capitalAppreciationFromFilter = 100
db.collection.find(
{
    $and: [
        {
            $or: [
                {
                    "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationFrom": {$exists: true, $lte: 100},
                    "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationTo": {$exists: false}
                },
                {
                    "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationFrom": {$exists: true, $lte: 100},
                    "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationTo": {$exists: true, $gte: 100}
                },
                {
                    "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationFrom": {$exists: false},
                    "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationTo": {$exists: true, $gte: 100}
                },
                {
                    "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationFrom": {$exists: true, $gte: 100},
                    "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationTo": {$exists: true, $gte: 100}
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
);

Example.
Filter - From / To: capitalAppreciationFromFilter = 100 / capitalAppreciationToFilter = 300
db.collection.find(
{
    $and: [
        {
            $or: [
                {
                    "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationFrom": {$exists: true, $lte: 300},
                     "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationTo": {$exists: true, $gte: 100}
                },
                {
                    "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationFrom": {$exists: true, $lte: 300},
                    "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationTo": {$exists: false}
                },
                {
                    "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationTo": {$exists: true, $gte: 100},
                    "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationFrom": {$exists: false}
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
);

Example.
Filter - To: capitalAppreciationToFilter = 300
db.collection.find(
{
    $and: [
        {
            $or: [
                {
                     "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationTo": {$lte: 300}
                },
                {
                     "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationFrom": {$lte: 300}
                },
                {
                     "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationTo": {$exists: true, $lte: 300},
                     "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationFrom": {$exists: false}
                },
                {
                     "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationTo": {$gte: 300},
                     "investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationFrom": {$exists: false}
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
);

Example.

This is not a valid answer, however it may help you to formalize a better question and enables other people to give you a solution.
Maybe as a starting point, you should make a small drawing to visualize your condition of intersecting ranges. Could be like this:
                     <- Input-Range  -> 
         ————————————|————————————————|———————————— Intersects?
Range 1:  |—————|                                      NO
Range 2:          |—————|                              YES
Range 3:                   |—————|                     YES
Range 4:                           |—————|             YES
Range 5:                                    |—————|    NO
Range 6:          |——————————————————————|             YES

Or for a single value, it could be
                Input-Value 
         ————————————|—————————————— Intersects?
Range 1:  |—————|                       NO
Range 2:          |—————|               YES
Range 3:                   |—————|      NO

Then it is easier to compose the condition by code.
You mention these three cases:

** - range in this case is:

value - from
values - from and to
value - to


You explained the first and second one, but nobody has a clue what "value - to" means.

Condition #1
occupancyRateFilterFrom - $gte: 30 
rentalYieldFilterFrom - $gte: 20 
rentalYieldFilterTo - $lte: 40

First range with from value - occupancyRateFilterFrom = $gte: 30
falls within the range of 30 to 60
(investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationFrom = 30 and investmentParameters.capitalAppreciationTo = 60).

Why does a occupancyRate filter has an effect on any capitalAppreciation range?

Condition #2
occupancyRateFilterFrom - $gte: 27 
rentalYieldFilterFrom - $gte: 20 
rentalYieldFilterTo - $lte: 40


Why do you expect all 4 documents should be selected? Document #1 is
{
   _id: 1,
   investmentParameters: {
      capitalAppreciationFrom: 30,
      capitalAppreciationTo: 60,
      rentalYieldFrom: 30,
      rentalYieldTo: 60,
      occupancyRateFrom: 30,
      occupancyRateTo: 60
   }
}

{ occupancyRateFrom: 30, occupancyRateTo: 60 } does not fall into 27, thus Condition #2 should not select document #1.

Next we have the condition:
capitalAppreciationFilterFrom - $gte: 62
occupancyRateFilterFrom - $gte: 16
rentalYieldFilterFrom - $gte: 20
rentalYieldFilterTo - $lte: 40

As a result of the selection, we should see the following objects:

Object #2
Object #3


Why?
Document #2 has { occupancyRateFrom: 17, occupancyRateTo: 80} and document #3 has { occupancyRateFrom: 27, occupancyRateTo: 87} which both do not fall into 16.
Note, I am not going to start again a discussion with comments. Take this answer, review your requirements, ask a new proper question with valid and consistent input data, expected result and what you have tried. Otherwise leave it!
