# MongoDB in Docker doesn't work (crashed with 4 exit code)

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm trying to run a simple docker container with mongod running inside following official up-to-date documentation: https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/docker but getting this error:

```
Take a look at your mongod configuration to see if something is wrong.
Could not init database.
['/usr/bin/mongod', '--bind_ip', '127.0.0.1', '--port', '27017', '--logappend', '--tlsMode', 'disabled', '--logpath', '/proc/1/fd/1', '--fork']
Subprocess failed with errorcode -4
```

I have no idea what's going wrong and this error does not give any context.

I tried many commands, with/without volume, with/without port mapping, but even the simpliest command gives me the above error:

```
docker run --name mongodb -d -e MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user -e MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass mongodb/mongodb-community-server:6.0-ubi8
```

I tried removing env variables by running this command

```
docker run --name mongodb -d mongodb/mongodb-community-server:6.0-ubi8
```

and got even more stupid error now from docker startup script:

```
Warning: File MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME_FILE is deprecated. Use MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME_FILE instead.
Warning: File MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE is deprecated. Use MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.py", line 594, in <module>
    subprocess.run(get_final_command_line_args(), check=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['mongod', '--bind_ip_all']' died with <Signals.SIGILL: 4>.
```

System info:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Docker: `Docker version 23.0.3, build 3e7cbfd`

Answer (score 0):

I tried `mongo` image and they all seem to not work with CPUs without AVX support even in docker containers. So you need a machine running docker with AVX CPU or pre 5.0.0 mongodb release. Since I already bought my VPS for 175$ annually I've decided to downgrade instead of once again moving to other machine:

```
docker run --name mongodb -d -p 27017:27017 -v $(pwd)/data/db:/data/db mongo:4.4.20@sha256:1017784ad6042dc22b961690ee19b2a9bfd5d1c37f8cf4b7ab3f51f142200409
```

Be sure to check if your system is running **on amd64 and not arm** by executing this command: `dpkg --print-architecture`. If it runs on arm, use another digest sha here:

```
docker run --name mongodb -d -p 27017:27017 -v $(pwd)/data/db:/data/db mongo:4.4.20@sha256: 8fe7ba54fc863276b9bea245ab51f1b5a4e28c25f449cfac450417d72167ddc1
```

It will persist data to ~/data/db from container and run on 27017 port so you can access container's mongodb by simply running

```
mongosh
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0/73084403#73084403