# Can't run docker mongo container image ( MONGO_VERSION=6.0.0) ERROR: child process failed, exited with 51

Tags: mongodb, docker, containers

I am on linux SO, I pulled this mongo image ( docker pull mongo:6.0) and when I try to run my docker mongo container image I got this error :

```
docker run -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=my_data --name mongo -p27017:27017 -ti mongo:6.0
```

Error:

```
warning: initdb logs cannot write to '/proc/1/fd/1', so they are in '/data/db/docker-initdb.log' instead
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 28
ERROR: child process failed, exited with 51
To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
```

PW: On Mongo versions <5 those commands worked with no problem, I checked some commands on the quick reference from https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo and it seems is needed --network flag with environment variables?? I need pass these -e(environment) variables described on my command.
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Comment: No, I am on linux SO, absolutely not related to your suggestion in any way, IDK where could you think of anything similar to your post solution comment...

Comment: this is unrelated to OS. It's about the fact that you can't use `mongo` binary for servers >= 6.0

Comment: ok, but where you see mongo in my command, It's only a name a --name mongo or I could put --name obama...

Comment: I downloaded mongo 5.0 and use it with the same commands and worked smoothly...

Comment: I am seeing the same error now on something that worked prior to Mongo 6. Did you ever get this issue resolved @mononoke83?

Comment: Hi @Tom, no sorry, I keep working with Mongo 5, but only I can say that Mongo 6 commands not worked in the same way as prev version, and you should check carefully the info and examples provided by the "How to use this image" section on the official docker mongo image https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo .
If you find out anything else useful please answer this question and I will validate it, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/docker the image name changed to

> mongodb/mongodb-community-server

I had the same problem and switching to that one made it work.

Another consideration MONGO_INITDB_... environment variables are deprecated and should be replaced by MONGODB_INITDB_...

```
docker run -e MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user -e MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MONGODB_INITDB_DATABASE=my_data --name mongo -p27017:27017 -ti mongodb/mongodb-community-server:6.0-ubi8
```

More tags available at
https://hub.docker.com/r/mongodb/mongodb-community-server/tags?page=1&name=6.0-

Comment: Ok, but you are using community version then, and I guess in docker hub exist 6.x mongo stable versions (no community). Have you tried other "no community" version?