# Issue Installing MongoDB 5.0.19: Missing mongo Binary on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, mongo-shell

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to install MongoDB 5.0.19 on my Ubuntu 20.04 system. After following the installation steps and confirming that the MongoDB service is up and running, I encountered a problem where the mongo binary is missing or inaccessible.

I have attempted various troubleshooting steps suggested online, including reinstalling MongoDB, verifying the installation path of mongosh, and creating symbolic links between mongosh and mongo. Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to access the MongoDB shell using the mongo command.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

1. Downloaded mongodb-org-server_5.0.19_amd64.deb from the official MongoDB website.
2. Installed the package using sudo dpkg -i mongodb-org-server_5.0.19_amd64.deb.
3. Started the MongoDB service using sudo systemctl start mongod.
4. Enabled automatic startup using sudo systemctl enable mongod.
5. Verified the service status using sudo systemctl status mongod, which shows that MongoDB is running.

However, when I attempt to run mongo to access the MongoDB shell, I receive the error message "bash: /usr/bin/mongo: No such file or directory."

I've double-checked that the mongosh binary is available in my system's PATH and have attempted to create symbolic links manually, but the issue persists.

Not installed anything else like monogo.exe or any other mongo shells

If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has insights into resolving this issue, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Please feel free to ask for any additional details, and I'll be more than happy to provide them.

Comment: mongo and mongosh are different binaries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0                                                                                                                                                 Thank you for your response! However, I'd like to clarify that I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 as my operating system. The steps you provided seem to be tailored for Windows, and I'm encountering the issue on Ubuntu.

Comment: It is the same. The legacy `mongo` shell has been removed and the new `mongosh` is not included in MongoDB server package for all platforms.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that and providing the information. I appreciate your help!