# missing mongo shell in mongodb under yocto

Tags: mongodb, yocto, scons

I have built a Mongodb from a default recipe in my Yocto project (based on Dunfell).

I copied relevant rpm packages to my target device and installed it (had to install some dependencies first).
mongod server runs great but for the life of me I am not able to find mongo shell and thus I am unable to interface with the server.

There seems to be no reference to it in the context of yocto anywhere on google. Without mongo shell I am unable to interface with the server for some evaluation I need to do before I invest more time into programming support for mongodb in my C++ app.

On my local machine I was able to install linux package : mongodb-clients but this seems to also not be available anywhere for yocto.
I tried connecting to the database from my local machine but either there is a security restriction in my office network or bare database (without admin user) is rejecting remote connections.

Am I missing something? Mongo shell is often presented as a given after installing mongodb but my mongodb package consists of only mongod and mongos.
Also complete lack of mention of mongodb-clients in the context of yocto threw me for a loop, is the mongodb popularity in yocto projects so low?

What I am asking is:

How can I obtain mongo shell for my yocto project, is mongodb-clients package bundled with something I am not aware of?

Optinally are there other mongodb cli clients available for yocto other than mongodb-shell?

After more searching:
GitHub repository used in recipe lists all 3 applications to be provided after the build, Unfortunately I no exactly nothing about SCons building system and cant properly locate where each executable is being built and maybe if some dependencies or build flags disable mongo shell executable.

Comment: what server version?

Comment: mongod --version                             
db version v4.2.2
git version: a0bbbff6ada159e19298d37946ac8dc4b497eadf
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64

Comment: mongo shell is no longer part of mongo server binaries. But only for server >= 6.0. It's strange that you have this issue for 4.2.2. However I didn't understand all the context you mention above.. See this post how to download a modern mongo shell (`mongosh`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0/73084403#73084403

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I tried some pre-built packages but with little luck. The issue is that I can't usually just install something. My custom linux built with Yocto has specific versions and specific dependencies, 9/10 times I have to build package I want from source because there is no pre-built binary compatible with my specific blend of package versions.

Comment: Did you add `shell` to `PACKAGECONFIG`?

Comment: The mongod service scripts usually contain the full path to the executables, so they work without adding anything to the path.  Does the 'bin' directory that contains the mongod executable not contain the mongo executable?