# Parse. MongoDB mongo installation

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, mongo-shell, mongosh

I am to go through an Parse example here: https://github.com/matrosovDev/parse-server-example but when I trying to install MongoDB I get this warning in my terminal, not sure if it is critical, but should I downgrade MongoDB or use alternative command to `mongo`?

```
Last login: Tue Jan 30 22:11:55 on ttys000
oleksandrmatrosov@Oleksandrs-MacBook-Pro ~ % mongo
MongoDB shell version v5.0.21
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("some UUID here") }
MongoDB server version: 7.0.2
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
================
Warning: the "mongo" shell has been superseded by "mongosh",
which delivers improved usability and compatibility.The "mongo" shell has been deprecated and will be removed in
an upcoming release.
For installation instructions, see
https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/install/
================
---
The server generated these startup warnings when booting: 
        2024-01-30T22:18:55.612+01:00: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted
---
>
```

when I use this in terminal I also have some deprecated `punycode`:

```
oleksandrmatrosov@Oleksandrs-MacBook-Pro ~ % mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: 65b968549ca94c44386ff0a1
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+2.1.3
(node:16795) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Using MongoDB:      7.0.2
Using Mongosh:      2.1.3
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0/73084403#73084403. Legacy shell should still work. However try a mongosh, I would assume in 99% cases it will behave close to mongo

Comment: regarding deprecating warning, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-5709