# .mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file=> add path isn't working for me

Tags: mongodb, powershell

I do read through
[.mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224959/mongo-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-o)
https://youtu.be/6_NSkDRXPZk?t=227

they said really clear need to add path in "environment variable"
**However is still not work**

following I detailed my steps(sorry for using 3 screenshot, otherwise I don't know how to present instead of code only )

**checking mongoDB path**: `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin`
[image: mongoDB path]

**adding path in environment variable**
[image: adding path in environment variable01]
[image: adding path in environment variable02]

**but the result when I check the mongoDB version :**
[image: result when I check the mongoDB version]

> C:\Users\chuan>mongo --version 'mongo'
> 不是內部或外部命令、可執行的程式或批次檔。

means

> .mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

I solved -

If there is no mongo.exe in your bin file, then download the mongo shell - mongosh from here

Use mongosh instead of mongo in the command line.

Check this Answer from dododo : "mongo shell no longer ships with server binaries."

Open "cmd" and type "mongod --version" in place of "mongo --version".

```
C:\Users\chuan>mongod --version
db version v6.0.2
Build Info: {
    "version": "6.0.2",
    "gitVersion": "94fb7dfc8b974f1f5343e7ea394d0d9deedba50e",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "windows",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```