# The term 'mongo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: mongodb, shell

After reviewing the fix provided in this link: [mongod command not recognized when trying to connect to a mongodb server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053893/mongod-command-not-recognized-when-trying-to-connect-to-a-mongodb-server/41507803)

I was still getting the same error. What I had to do was simply restart my powershell and the issue was resolved.

So this is not actually a question but a comment. I had to do this because I don't have enough reputation to make a comment yet. (smiles)