# mongo : The term 'mongo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

when i try to connect mongodb using vs i am getting an this error.

i already installed shell also add envirnment variable
also vist [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053893/mongo-command-not-recognized-when-trying-to-connect-to-a-mongodb-server page](https://stackoverflow.com) 
but problem is still
in cmd **mongosh** is recognized but i am getting error using **mongo**
in vs code i already ad extension of mongodb and connect successfully
successfulladd "devDependencies": {
"nodemon": "^3.0.3"
}

Comment: in version 6.0 and above mongo is mongosh