# 'mongo' is working, but 'mongod' is not working in CMD

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have installed MongoDB properly.

Added `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin` to `Path` in Environment variables.

Then, when I enter `mongod` command in command prompt (at C:\),I get the following error:

`'mongod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

`mongo` command works fine!! `mongo --version` too works, but not `mongod`.

**Update:**

After going throught the documentation of MongoDB, I found that `mongod.exe` file is missing in my `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin` directory. Why did this happen?

Comment: Why you need to run `mongod` when you can run `mongo` in cmd.

Comment: Did you check `mogod` is present in the `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin` folder?

Comment: @Mani: Yea, `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin` folder is present which is why `mongo --version` is responding. By 'I have installed MongoDB properly', I meant that the mongoDB folder is created in C drive.

Comment: @AmolBJamkar: I need to run `mongod` to create a local mongoDB server to which I'll connect using `mongo`

Comment: @shrivamsi ok, you said `mongo` is working in cmd so I assumed that you can connect to your DB.

Comment: By going through the documentation of MongoDB, I found that there is not file named `mongod.exe` in my `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin` which is why this error is happening. But why is it that I do not have that particular file?

Comment: @SrivamsiMalladi That why I asked did you find mogod file in the installed folder. In this case, your installation has issues. Uninstall and reinstall MongoDB again.

Comment: @Mani: I tried uninstalling and installing MongoDB several times, but the issue is not getting resolved.

Comment: @AmolBJamkar: I can connect to any DB using `mongo`. But to connect to my local DB, i will first need to create one using `mongod`, right?

Comment: Where did you get the MongoDB installable? Try getting the latest version from MongoDB downloads and install it again.

Comment: @Mani: I am downloading from MongoDB downloads only. Don't know why this is happening. I took the `mongod.exe` file from somewhere else and placed it in the appropriate directory, now it's working fine.

Comment: @shrivamsi this question might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883045/mongodb-difference-between-running-mongo-and-mongod-databases

Comment: @AmolBJamkar: oh thanks