# How to connect Mongodb with IntellijIdea in windows?

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea, mongodb-java

I have one project and it uses mongodb to run. I have installed monogdb on windows but i am not getting what to do next. I ran "**mongo**" command from the installation directory to at least start the database but in some threads I have seen we need to run mongod command to start the database but it is giving error:

```
2020-07-31T13:29:14.910+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-07-31T13:29:14.913+0530 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2020-07-31T13:29:14.915+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=10540 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=DESKTOP-UC7933K
2020-07-31T13:29:14.916+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2020-07-31T13:29:14.916+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.8
2020-07-31T13:29:14.917+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 43d25964249164d76d5e04dd6cf38f6111e21f5f
2020-07-31T13:29:14.917+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-07-31T13:29:14.918+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-07-31T13:29:14.918+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-07-31T13:29:14.918+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2012plus
2020-07-31T13:29:14.919+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-07-31T13:29:14.919+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-07-31T13:29:14.920+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2020-07-31T13:29:14.923+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory C:\data\db\ not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file., terminating
2020-07-31T13:29:14.923+0530 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2020-07-31T13:29:14.925+0530 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2020-07-31T13:29:14.925+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-07-31T13:29:14.926+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

So please help me to link the mongodb with the project.

Comment: Create folder `C:\data\db` and try starting the `mongod`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5490907/4699195

Comment: @hhharsha36 the cursor is blinking after " Marking collection local.oplog.rs as collection version: <unsharded>" so it has started?

Comment: What programming language are you using to connect to the MongoDB database (from the IDE)?

Comment: i am using java

Comment: Please specify  driver and MongoDB versions.

Comment: MongoDb: v4.2.8 and which driver version?

Comment: [MongoDB Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/). You are trying to connect to the database from a Java application?

Comment: ok driver version is 3.9.0

Comment: You have to start the MongoDB server, a.k.a. `mongod`, before you can access the database from Java. Have you done that? Try to do it from Windows command prompt. Try the appropriate [MongoDB Tutorials](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/installation/).

Comment: yes  the server is running, now how do i connect it with intellij idea?

Comment: There are tutorials for connectiong, performng CRUD operations, etc., in the link I have provided in the earlier comment for the Java driver.

Comment: ok i will try, thanks